# Matplotlib.pyplot - Deactivate axes in figure. /Axis of figure overlap with axes of subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, figure

```
%load_ext autoreload 
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, date
from datetime import date as dt
import math
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
from pylab import plot,show
from matplotlib import ticker
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pylab as pl

x_min_global=datetime.date(2010,1, 1)- timedelta(days=180)
x_max_global=datetime.date(2015,1, 1)+ timedelta(days=180)

d = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(155),columns=['Zeros'])
d = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(2),columns=['Zeros'])

wd=os.getcwd()

def format_date(x, pos=None):
            return pl.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

with PdfPages(wd+'/Plots.pdf') as pdf:

    #Plot 1: All
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white',frameon=True,figsize=(30, 30))
    plt.title('Page One ', y=1.08)

    axes1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1,frameon=False)

    axes1.set_xlim(x_min_global,x_max_global)

    axes1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))

    #Plot line a at 0-level
    axes1.plot([x_min_global,x_max_global],d.loc[0:1],color='k', linewidth=2.0, markersize=10.0)     

    # labels and legend
    axes1.set_title('Plot 1')
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=10)
    plt.ylabel('Y-Values', fontsize=10)
    axes1.legend(loc='upper left')

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #Plot 2: 
    axes1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2,frameon=False)

    axes1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))

    #Plot line a at 0-level
    axes1.plot([x_min_global,x_max_global],d.loc[0:1],color='k', linewidth=2.0, markersize=10.0)

    # labels and legend
    axes1.set_title('Plot 2')
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=10)
    plt.ylabel('Y-Values', fontsize=10)
    axes1.legend(loc='upper left')

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #Plot 3:
    axes2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3,frameon=False)

    axes2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))

    #Plot line a at 0-level
    axes2.plot([x_min_global,x_max_global],d.loc[0:1],color='k', linewidth=2.0, markersize=10.0)

    # labels and legend
    axes2.set_title('Plot 3')
    plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=10)
    plt.ylabel('Y-Values', fontsize=10)
    axes2.legend(loc='upper left')

    pdf.savefig(frameon=False,transparent=False,papertype='a4')  # saves the current figure into a pdf page
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

My problem is that in the plot generated by code above the axis of the figure and the sublpots seem to overlap (see red rectangles in picture). I tried to turn off the axes in the figure. However, I was not able to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Output of Code / Problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the axes completely, you should try:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

If that doesn't work (or doesn't do what you want it to), try:

```
cur_axes = plt.gca()
cur_axes.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
cur_axes.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that plt.axis('off') will remove both x and y axes.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer evtoh. However, both of the suggestions do not yield the result I desire. If I try the suggestions above, only the values from 0 to 1.0 remain at the bottom. The date values 2010-01-01 to 2015-01-01 are removed, however. Do you maybe have any other suggestions?

Comment: oh, ok. Thank you anyways, evtoh. Does anyone else maybe have a suggestion?

Comment: Im sorry, evtoh. Actually it does work. I just put your lines of code in the wrong place. It had to place it directly after the line 'fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white',frameon=True,figsize=(30, 30))' in my example above. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!